# How to install npm package globally on heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, graphql, prisma

I need to use lerna package while running the yarn start command.

```
"build:backend": "lerna run build --stream --ignore @realworld/dashboard",
"start:backend": "lerna exec --stream --scope=@realworld/backend -- yarn start",
"start": "yarn build:backend && yarn start:backend",
```

But, I when I gave `git push heroku master`, heroku couldn't find lerna

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you add `lerna` to your `package.json` as dependency?

Comment: Yes. But locally in my pc, I have installed this package using npm i -g lerna

Comment: What's the exact error message? And does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849470/heroku-cant-find-package-json-during-build-although-i-have-it

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: lerna: not found

Comment: Also this maybe? https://jaketrent.com/post/deploy-lerna-packages-heroku/

Comment: Share your `package.json`. Are you certain lerna is a dependency and not a devdependency?